# Cannot upgrade Paramiko

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

Im trying to upgrade Paramiko for my raspberry pi, but for some reason I just cant get it to upgrade to the newest version. Just as a precursor CFFI is upgraded.

The current version of Paramiko installed is outdated: paramiko==1.15.1

```
root@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit-Motor-HAT-Python-Library/examples# pip freeze
Adafruit-GPIO==1.0.3
Adafruit-MotorHAT==1.4.0
Adafruit-PureIO==0.2.1
Pillow==2.6.1
RPi.GPIO==0.6.3
RTIMULib==7.2.1
argparse==1.2.1
cffi==0.8.6
chardet==2.3.0
colorama==0.3.2
ecdsa==0.11
gpiozero==1.4.0
html5lib==0.999
lxkeymap==0.1
mcpi==0.1.1
ndg-httpsclient==0.3.2
numpy==1.8.2
paramiko==1.15.1
picamera==1.13
pifacecommon==4.2.1
pifacedigitalio==3.1.0
ply==3.4
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyasn1==0.1.7
pycparser==2.10
pycrypto==2.6.1
pygame==1.9.2a0
pygobject==3.14.0
pyserial==2.6
requests==2.4.3
sense-hat==2.2.0
six==1.8.0
smbus==1.1
spidev==3.0
urllib3==1.9.1
wheel==0.24.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

When I try upgrade I get the following:

```
 pip install paramiko --upgrade
Downloading/unpacking paramiko from https://pypi.python.org/packages/be/9f/2b899b028aec1f3973253c0cf8dda6fbff65f4930f7ebedc43033e9f1b18/paramiko-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=53bf4a66ff143bda10b4b4868effac0d
  Downloading paramiko-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (192kB): 192kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking pyasn1>=0.1.7 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/ba/fe/02e3e2ee243966b143657fb8bd6bc97595841163b6d8c26820944acaec4d/pyasn1-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=766a80e17caafe179f0b6d56569c63d4 (from paramiko)
  Downloading pyasn1-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB): 71kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking bcrypt>=3.1.3 (from paramiko)
  Downloading bcrypt-3.1.4.tar.gz (42kB): 42kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-NEwtcG/bcrypt/setup.py) egg_info for package bcrypt

    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'requirements.txt'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tasks.py'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'wheel-scripts'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'Jenkinsfile'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.jenkins'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory '.jenkins'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'wheel-scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
Downloading/unpacking pynacl>=1.0.1 (from paramiko)
  Downloading PyNaCl-1.2.1.tar.gz (3.3MB): 3.3MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-NEwtcG/pynacl/setup.py) egg_info for package pynacl
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-NEwtcG/pynacl/setup.py", line 251, in <module>
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__
        _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 301, in finalize_options
        ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
        ['__name__'])
    ImportError: No module named setuptools_ext
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-NEwtcG/pynacl/setup.py", line 251, in <module>

    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 266, in __init__

    _Distribution.__init__(self,attrs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 287, in __init__

    self.finalize_options()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 301, in finalize_options

    ep.load()(self, ep.name, value)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load

    ['__name__'])

ImportError: No module named setuptools_ext

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-NEwtcG/pynacl
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Suggestions welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing setuptools to meet the dependency issue.

```
pip install setuptools
```

Then you can upgrade paramiko version usuing

```
pip install paramiko --upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks i had tried that, but it looks to already installed:

root@raspberrypi:~# pip install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
root@raspberrypi:

Comment: pip install --upgrade cffi

Comment: Thanks, ive done that already. Unfortunately it did not help. Im pulling my hair out. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, fixed it after upgrade in pip3.

run:
`pip3 install pip --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the Paramiko defect I was hitting on version 1.15.1 and did not need to do any upgrade. My suspicion is my PI has a corrupt file which is causing the upgrade to fail.